# MySql Query: ordering by two fields in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have two tables storing members data

members: id, field1, field2 and field3...

members_extra: memberId, someExtraField1 and someExtraField2

members_extra.memberId  is a Foreign Key referencing members.id

'members_extra' may or may not have related rows for rows in 'members'

let's say: I have 1000 members in 'members', and I have 50 rows in 'members_extra' containing extra info

now I want to search 'members' and order the results according to 'member.field2'... but I want members who have extra info (in members_extra) to be listed before those who don't have extra info

now I use member.field3 as ENUM('true','false') which indicates whether this member has extra info or not and ordering like this: ORDER BY field3 ASC, field2 ASC... this works fine, but I don't like the approach, since I have to update members.field3 every time I insert or delete something from members_extra

how to do this without using members.field3?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can include an ORDER BY on whether members_extra.memberId is present or not:

```
SELECT *
FROM members
LEFT JOIN members_extra
ON members.id = members_extra.memberId
ORDER BY members_extra.memberId IS NULL, members.field2
```

Now you don't need members.field3 and you can delete it from your schema. This will make your database closer to normalized form.

Answer (score 0):

```
order by member_extra.something desc
```

first, which I believe will list NULLs after non-NULLs, or

```
order by case when member_extra.something IS NOT NULL 1 else 2 end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT members.id, 
       members.field1, 
       members_extra.someExtraField1,
       Ordering = CASE members_extra.memberId WHEN NULL THEN 'Z' ELSE 'A' END 
   FROM members 
        LEFT JOIN 
        members_extra ON members.Id = members_extra.memberId
  ORDER BY Ordering
```

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU VERY MUCH

This works!!!

```
    SELECT * FROM members LEFT JOIN members_extra ON members.id = members_extra.memberId ORDER BY members_extra.memberId IS NULL, members.field2`enter code here`
```

This gives an Error:

> ```
> SELECT members.id, members.field1, members_extra.someExtraField1,
> ```
>
> Ordering = CASE members_extra.memberId WHEN NULL THEN 'Z' ELSE 'A' END
>   FROM members LEFT JOIN members_extra ON members.Id = members_extra.memberId
>   ORDER BY Ordering

It should be like this:

> Blockquote
>
> ```
> SELECT members.id, members.field1, members_extra.someExtraField1,
> ```
>
> CASE members_extra.memberId WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END **AS Ordering** 
>   FROM members LEFT JOIN members_extra ON members.Id = members_extra.memberId
>   ORDER BY Ordering
>
> Blockquote

One strange thing though... when I use the last query I always get ordering=1.. even though there is no corresponding rows in members_extra